# Linux : How to use tail option in opened log file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using Putty to connect to Linux server .

I opened a Log file in Linux server using the $ tail -f error_log

A log file has been displayed  .

Please tell me how can i do   ps –ef|grep java on to the opened Log file

Thank you .

Comment: What, from within `tail`? Quit tail, and run `grep java < error_log`.

Comment: @new123456: Sidenote, `grep -options "searchterm" [file]`

Comment: @new123456 `grep java error_log` works too

Comment: I'd be easier if you told us exactly what is that you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand but I think I know what you're asking.

Doing this:

`tail -f logfile | grep java`

will show you lines with the text `java` in the file as the file is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a regularly updated list of java processes, you can use `watch`:

```
watch 'ps -ef | grep [j]ava'
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want a regularly updated list of the process you are looking for you can do so:

```
vim error_log
```

and when inside the file reading, just do a simple search for what are you looking for.

```
/java
```

and press 'n' for next result.

Check this link: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace for **vim** Search & replace cheatsheet